# Find the point P.

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima, coordinate-systems

> Given two points $A(1,2), B(2,3)$ and a line $L:2x+3y+5=0$. If $P$ is a variable point on $L$. Locate $P$ if
>
> $1)\;PA+PB$ is minimum
>
> $2)\;|PA-PB|$ is maximum

I assumed the point to be $(-1.5y-2.5,y)$ and applied distance formula for both, I took $f(P)=|PA|$ and $g(P)=|PB|$ and then,

For

$1)$
$$
g'(P)+f'(P)=0 \\
g''(P)+f''(P)>0
$$

$2)$
$$
g'(P)-f'(P)=0 \\
g''(P)-f''(P)<0
$$

It makes me hard to solve these and double check. So, I took help of wolfram alpha. Is there any other method which helps solve quickly and manually?

Comment: $|PA+PB|$ is not well defined. Do you have in mind $|PA|+|PB|?$ Similarly for the difference.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEAoLWg8Uns

Comment: And the maximum of the difference is quite obvious, if you draw a sketch.

Comment: @user376343 now you can see

Comment: Given two points, locus of curve where sum of distance is a constant is an ellipse (sum being equal to length of major axis) and locus of curve where difference of distance is a constant is an hyperbola (difference being equal to length of major axis). In both cases, the line joining the two points is major axis.

So, to make to sum minimum, the idea is to find the ellipse which is tangent to the line. The difference is maximum when the line becomes tangent to both branches of hyperbola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ Let the reflection of $B$ in $\overleftrightarrow{L}: y=-\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{5}{3}$ be $B'$ and let $\overleftrightarrow{AB'}$ cuts the line $\overleftrightarrow{L}$ at $P$, then because the triange $\triangle BPB'$ is isoceles with $PB=P'B$, $PA+PB=PA+PB'=AB'$ and we claim that this is the minumum value. Because, for another point $Q$ on $\overleftrightarrow{L}$, $QA+QB$ will be greater than $AB'$  by triangular inequality in the triangle $\triangle AQB'$. So, how do we find this $P$? The normal of $\overleftrightarrow{L}$ is $\langle2,3\rangle$, so the line through $B(2,3)$ and $B'$ has slope $3/2$ and it is $y=\frac{3}{2}x$. It cuts $\overleftrightarrow{L}$ at $M(-\frac{10}{13},-\frac{15}{13})$. From $B+B'=2M$ we have $B'(-\frac{46}{13},-\frac{69}{13})$. The line throgh $A(1,2)$ and $B'$ is $y=\frac{95}{59}x+\frac{23}{59}$ and it cuts $\overleftrightarrow{L}$ at $P(-\frac{28}{11},-\frac{33}{31})$. And $AP+PB=AB'=\sqrt{74}$ is the minum value.

$2)$ Let the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ cuts the line $\overleftrightarrow{L}$ at  $P$. Then $|AP-BP|=AB=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(3-2)^2}=\sqrt2$ is the maximum, because for another point $Q$ on the line $\overleftrightarrow{L}$, by triangular inequality on the triangle $\triangle AQB$, we would have $|AQ-QB|<AB$.

Comment: In 1st case if $B', Q, A$ are colinear minimum value of $AQ+BQ=AQ+B'Q=AB'$. Isn't it?

Comment: @Anonymous You were tricking me. Yes. Thanks. This must be noted well. Did we?

Answer (score 1):

$(x_0, y_0) = (-1, -1)$ is a point belonging to the line $L$.

Vector $\mathbf{n}=\overline{(2, 3)}$ is a *normal* vector to the line $L\Rightarrow$ vector $\mathbf{s} = \overline{(-3, 2)}$ is parallel to $L$.

Then, any point $P∈ L$ can be represented in a parametric form as

$$
P(t) = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
P_x &= -1-3t \\
P_y &= -1+2t
\end{aligned}
\right., \: t\in (-\infty, +\infty).
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
PA \pm PB &= \sqrt{(1-(-1-3t))^2+(2-(-1+2t))^2} \pm \sqrt{(2-(-1-3t))^2+(3-(-1+2t))^2} = \\
&= \sqrt{(2+3t)^2+(3-2t)^2}\pm\sqrt{(3+3t)^2+(4-2t)^2} = \\
&= \sqrt{13t^2+13}\pm\sqrt{13t^2+3t+25}\\ \\
PA+PB \rightarrow \min &\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{13t^2+13}+\sqrt{13t^2+3t+25} \rightarrow \min. \\
|PA-PB| \rightarrow \max &\Leftrightarrow \left|\sqrt{13t^2+13}-\sqrt{13t^2+3t+25}\right| \rightarrow \max.
\end{aligned}
$$

Once you have a parameter value for $t$, say $t^*$, you can find $P^* = P(t^*)$.